# Why is executing "docker exec" killing my SSH session?

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, docker-exec

Let's say I have two servers, `A` and `B`. I also have a `bash` script that is executed on server `A` that looks like this:

### build_test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@B <<'ENDSSH'
echo "doing test"
bash -ex test.sh
echo "completed test"
ENDSSH
```

### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -i my_container /bin/bash -c "echo hi!"
```

The problem is that `completed test` does not get printed to the terminal.

Here's the output of running `build_test.sh`:

```
$ ./build_test
doing test
+ docker exec -i my_container /bin/bash -c "echo hi!"
hi!
```

I'm expecting `completed test` to be output after `hi!`, but it isn't. How do I fix this?

Comment: `docker` is probably consuming the rest of the standard input it inherits from `ssh` (which is the script you are trying to run).

Comment: If so, is there any way to tell docker to not do that?

Comment: `docker ... < /dev/null`.

Comment: That worked! Make that an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: You could also remove the `-i` flag.

Comment: I still want the output of `docker exec` to be printed to stdout. Won't removing `-i` prevent the output of `docker exec` from being printed to stdout?

Comment: @NathanJones the `-i` is for stdin. You'll get stdout/stderr as long as you do not detach with `-d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker` is consuming, though not using, its standard input, which it inherits from `test.sh`. `test.sh` inherits its standard input from `bash`, which inherits its standard input from `ssh`. This means that `docker` itself is reading the last line of the script before the remote shell can.

To fix, just redirect docker's standard input from `/dev/null`.

```
docker exec -i my_container /bin/bash -c "echo hi!" < /dev/null
```